# Reduced Advertising privilege on DBA.SE

Tags: bug, status-completed

This site currently carries ads for SolarWinds,  both full-width banners  (shown below) and sidebar ads. [According to Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/246563/), full-width ads should be disabled for users with 200+ reputation, like it is done on SO, SF and SU.

Yet, this privilege does not appear in the [Help Center](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges):

> [image: privs]

So there is either a Help Center bug, or perhaps the privilege is not active on this site at all. (I don't have 200 rep, so I don't know which way it is.)

---

[image: ad]

Comment: That's odd-- I can see it: http://i.imgur.com/6TZ6WaJ.png

Comment: @stevvve Shog9 fixed it an hour before your comment, hence the [tag:status-completed] tag.